# cannot connect to Google Cloud SQL from localhost phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

I'd like to move all of my databases at my local database to Google Cloud SQL and followed this tutorial here: https://docs.bitnami.com/google/how-to/migrate-database-cloud-sql/
but when I made some addition to config.inc.php:

```
$i++;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Google Cloud SQL'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '35.247.134.165';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '***';//my username
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password’] = '***';//my password
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = TRUE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

and then reloaded the phpMyAdmin client webpage, but it showed a totally blank page...[like this](http://prntscr.com/t4e5wj)
I don't know where it did wrong here...
Thank you...

Comment: Before using phpmyadmin to connect, have you tried using another database client to connect to your Cloud SQL instance? This would help determining where the issue is, either on your config file or in the properties of your Cloud SQL instance? You can use below links to try different approaches to connect. Also, is the ip of your instance public or private? 
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart#connect
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip

Comment: the ip of my instance is Public IP address

Comment: Have you tried using another database client to connect? Again this can help identify where the issue lies either on your configuration side or the server side.

Comment: If you have proof that your Cloud SQL instance is unreachable with any database client, it may be also be worth to reach out to support[1] but only when you have confirmed the latter. [1] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases

Answer (score 2):

I have reviewed your configuration and identified where the issue lies.

The issue is in your auth_type statement, please look at my config.ini.php

```
<?php
$i=0;  
$i++;  
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Google Cloud SQL'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '12.345.678.901';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password’] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
?>
```

Furthermore when I was connecting phpmyadmin to Cloud SQL mysql I received timeouts because my instance was not allowing external connections.
To solve this I did the following:

1. I clicked on the name of my Cloud SQL instance
2. Then I clicked on the tab Connections;here there is a section called 'Authorized Networks' under 'Public IP' checkbox.
3. Finally I added the CIDR of my network or if you are only testing it for now, you can also add 0.0.0.0/0;be careful, the last CIDR value will allow any external network to try to connect to your Cloud SQL instance.

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: I've switched auth_type as config...And for the Public IP section, I originally added my current IP address... But I also added 0.0.0.0/0 to newly created Public IP authorized network... but it did not work either.